# How to use an ID attribute to style an element in css?

Tags: html, css

The code below needs a attribute id in the form element but I can't figure out what does it mean. Any suggestions?

[image]//i.stack.imgur.com/pT4GE.png

```
 #cat-photo-form
 {
  background-color: green;


}

<form

action = "/submit-cat-photo" id ="cat-photo-form">
  <label><input type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor" checked> Indoor</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor"> Outdoor</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="personality" checked> Loving</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="personality"> Lazy</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="personality"> Energetic</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="cat photo URL" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: you have two ID in the form

Comment: Sorry, only one.

Comment: still 2 id in the screenshot, so we can suppose this is still the issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`id` and `class` are atrributes that you include inside the elements in order to manipulate them in the css.
 `id` must be unique in the current html element. 
But more than one html element can have the same `class`.
   As for your example you should have in the form the `id cat-photo-form.`You don't need the second `id cat-form-element` that you inside. Like so:

```
<style>
     #cat-photo-form
     {
      background-color: green;
    }
</style>
    <form action = "/submit-cat-photo" id ="cat-photo-form">
      <label><input type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor" checked> Indoor</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor"> Outdoor</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="personality" checked> Loving</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="personality"> Lazy</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="personality"> Energetic</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="cat photo URL" required>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I delete the second id does not matter because I'll remain with the same error like you can see in the third topic:"Make sure your form element has an id attribute. ". Can you explain me that?  I have an id attribute in the form element, but stil doesn't work.

Comment: Your code is right. The question that you requested to answer is confirm. You aldready have an id with that name in your form. Probably something went wrong with the webiste platform and not in your code. I'm telling that because i had many times the same problem in this website. Although my code is correct, i was getting an error. So discuss that thing in the chat of the website to get some answers.

Comment: @KaroTardígrado so why this answer is got accepted if it doesn't solve your issue ?